# How to construct a TarFile object in memory from byte buffer in Python 3?

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, tar, tarfile

Is it possible to create a TarFile object in memory using a buffer containing the tar data without having to write the TarFile to disk and open it up again? We get the bytes sent over a socket.

Something like this:

```
import tarfile
byte_array = client.read_bytes()
tar = tarfile.open(byte_array) # how to do this?
# use "tar" as a regular TarFile object
for member in tar.getmembers():
    f = tar.extractfile(member)
    print(f)
```

Note: one of the reasons for doing this is that we eventually want to be able to do this with multiple threads simultaneously, so using a temp file might be overridden if two threads try to do it at the same time.

Thank you for any and all help!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

BytesIO() from [IO module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) does exactly what you need.

```
import tarfile, io
byte_array = client.read_bytes()
file_like_object = io.BytesIO(byte_array)
tar = tarfile.open(fileobj=file_like_object)
# use "tar" as a regular TarFile object
for member in tar.getmembers():
    f = tar.extractfile(member)
    print(f)
```

Comment: might have to add the mode, depending on what you're doing (archive in an archive) tarfile.open(fileobj=byte_stream, mode='r:gz')

Comment: ^ exactly.  I had gotten to `fileobj=file_like_object` and wasn't doing `mode=` just giving the mode which isn't valid python x0 (they're all positional arguments, but the docs show `"filename", "r:gz"` -- if you're using stuff from memory you need to `fileobj=..., mode=...` explicitly!

Comment: ...and `tar.close()`. also supports _context manager_

Answer (score 11):

Sure, something like this:

```
import io

io_bytes = io.BytesIO(byte_array)

tar = tarfile.open(fileobj=io_bytes, mode='r')
```

(Adjust `mode` to fit the format of your tar file, e.g. possibly `mode='r:gz', etc.)