# Use gzip with archive with multiple files in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding, gzip, compression

So basically I have a file system like this:

```
main_archive.tar.gz
  main_archive.tar
    sub_archive.xml.gz
      actual_file.xml
```

There are hundreds of files in this archive... So basically, can the `gzip` package be used with multiple files in Python 3? I've only used it with a single file zipped so I'm at a loss on how to go over multiple files or multiple levels of "zipping".

My usual method of decompressing is:

```
with gzip.open(file_path, "rb") as f:
  for ln in f.readlines():
    *decode encoding here*
```

Of course, this has multiple problems because usually "f" is just a file... But now I'm not sure what it represents?

Any help/advice would be much appreciated!

EDIT 1:

I've accepted the answer below, but if you're looking for similar code, my backbone was basically:

```
tar = tarfile.open(file_path, mode="r")
for member in tar.getmembers():
    f = tar.extractfile(member)
    if verbose:
        print("Decoding", member.name, "...")
    with gzip.open(f, "rb") as temp:
        decoded = temp.read().decode("UTF-8")
        e = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse(decoded).getroot()
        for child in e:
            print(child.tag)
            print(child.attrib)
            print("\n\n")

tar.close()
```

Main packages used were `gzip`, `tarfile`, and `xml.etree.ElementTree`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gzip` only supports compressing a single file or stream. In your case, the extracted stream is a `tar` object, so you'd use Python's [`tarfile` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html) to manipulate the extracted contents. This library actually knows how to cope with `.tar.gz` so you don't need to explicitly extract the `gzip` yourself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857792/how-to-construct-a-tarfile-object-in-memory-from-byte-buffer-in-python-3 has some useful code examples.

Answer (score 0):

Use Python's tarfile to get the contained files, and then Python's gzip again inside the loop to extract the xml.