How can you verify two tar.gz files are identical
I am making a sharing protocol, and when you share a folder it gets tar.gz-ipped and inserted in a folder.
It's created like this:
with tarfile.open(full_data_name, "w:gz", format=GNU_FORMAT) as tar_handle:
   ...
   tar_handle.add(file_path)

When you do that again, I'd like to verify and check if new tar.gz is identical to the old one (so I do not need to re-publish it).
I know about pkgdiff and that works fine, but I'd like to do it in python.
I also know I can do it manually, de-zip&tar the files, load up the content and verify byte wise, but isn't there some simpler and less resource hungry method?
I have tried to just check the contents of the tar.gz files (removing the timestamp at byte 4-7) but that only works sometimes, so I guess there is some random reshuffling in the tar part or some randomness in the gz, as pkgdiff says they are the same, but a hex editor shows lots of differences.

You seem to have already concluded that there isn't really. Perhaps you should investigate whether other archive formats are more deterministic in this scenario instead.

Define "identical". The same path names with the same data are present? Also with the same file attributes? Also in the same order? Also with the same subdirectory paths as entries? And with the same subdirectory attributes? And those in the same order with the files? Using the same tar format? With the same compression? With the same compressed data?

Why not just run pkgdiff from Python?

@MarkAdler I don't want to have users install software basically. For the 'identical' ; if I add the same files to two tar.gz, they are the same.

@tripleee Got my answer below -:)

You can extract the files in memory and compute checksums. This avoids extracting the entire archive physically.
import tarfile
import hashlib

def get_tar_checksum(tar_path):
    with tarfile.open(tar_path, "r:gz") as tar:
        checksums = {}
        for member in tar.getmembers():
            if member.isfile():
                file_data = tar.extractfile(member).read()
                checksums[member.name] = hashlib.sha256(file_data).hexdigest()
    return checksums


def tar_equal(tar_path1, tar_path2):
    return get_tar_checksum(tar_path1) == get_tar_checksum(tar_path2)

# Usage
tar1 = "path/to/first.tar.gz"
tar2 = "path/to/second.tar.gz"

if tar_equal(tar1, tar2):
    print("The tar.gz files are identical.")
else:
    print("The tar.gz files are different.")

The tar_equal(tar_path1, tar_path2) method returns True if the compared tars are identical. You can implement your logic from there.

This will tell you if the content is identical, but by using a dict the file order won't be checked.

Work, and if you have the tar.gz in memory, you can adjust the function with the answer to another question here by Warren Weckesser https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857792/how-to-construct-a-tarfile-object-in-memory-from-byte-buffer-in-python-3

@MarkRansom True, but if the tar.gz files contain the same files, even unordered, they will compare as identic. Which is fine for me, but potentially not for someone wanting the same order too for whatever reason.

@Valmond it was not clear from your question whether you cared about order or not, so I thought I'd leave a warning (not just for you but for others).  Replacing the dict with a list of tuples would solve the problem.
